# Using pipe(): How do I allow multiple child processes to execute simultaneously

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I'm using `pipe()` to split up a file by index, send that index to child processes, have the child process calculate the sum of the numbers in its designated block of the file, and return its sum to the parent.

My children seem to execute in order, where I would *like* them to execute at the same time to make this process more efficient.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int numchild;
struct timeval stop, start;
int i, j, len, ret, fpos=0, val, count=0, total=0, alltotal=0;
pid_t pid;
int nums = 1000;
FILE * file;

printf("How many children to use: ");
scanf("%d", &numchild);
printf("\nWill use %d child process(es).\n", numchild);

gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
int fd[numchild][2]; //parent to child. one for each
int results[2]; //all children to parent
pipe(results);

fd_set result_fd;
FD_ZERO(&result_fd);
FD_SET(results[0], &result_fd);
struct timeval tm = {.tv_sec=0, .tv_usec=1};

// create all pipes
for (i=0; i<numchild; i++)
{
    pipe(fd[i]);
}

for (i=0; i<numchild; i++)
{
    if((pid = fork()) == 0) // child process
    {
        pid = getpid();

        // read from parent
        len = read(fd[i][0], &fpos, sizeof(fpos));
        if (len > 0)
        {
            file = fopen("file1.dat", "r");
            fseek (file, fpos, SEEK_SET);
            count = 0;
            total = 0;

            printf("Child(%d): Recieved position: %d\n", pid, fpos);

            // read from file starting at fpos
            // add values read to a total value
            while (count < (nums/numchild))
            {
                fscanf(file, "%i", &val);
                total += val;
                count++;
            }
            //write to parent
            write(results[1], &total, sizeof(total));
            printf("Child(%d): Sent %d to parent.\n", pid, total);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Child(%d): Error with len\n", pid);
        }
        _exit(0);
    }

    // parent process
    pid = getpid();

    fpos = ((i*nums*5)/numchild); // 5 is the offset of the file values

    // write to child process
    printf("Parent(%d): Sending file position to child\n", pid);
    write(fd[i][1], &fpos, sizeof(fpos));

    // wait for child responce
    ret = select(FD_SETSIZE+1, &result_fd, NULL, NULL, NULL); //&tm
    if (FD_ISSET(results[0], &result_fd))
    {
        ret = read(results[0], &total, sizeof(total));

        // output total
        printf("Parent(%d): Recieved %d from child.\n", pid, total);
        alltotal += total;
        //printf("\tParent(%d): Total: %d\n", pid, alltotal);
    }
}
wait(0);
gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
printf("\tTime elapsed: %lu microseconds\n", stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
printf("\tParent(%d): Total: %d\n", pid, alltotal);
}
```

Please let me know what I need to change to have the child processes run simultaneously (not wait to run at the exact same time, but run as soon as the parent gives them their index, instead of waiting for the previous child to complete).

Comment: Not calling `wait()` each time through the loop to ensure your parent waits for the child to complete before `fork()`ing a new one would be a good place to start. Create them all, and then `wait()` for them all once they're running.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths where do you suggest I put the `wait()`? I assume you mean within the child fork(), but I don't know after that.

Comment: After the code that forks all the processes, and after the code where the parent has done what it needs to with each one.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I've added wait(0) in two places based on my understanding. One right inside the `if((pid=fork())==0)` and one at the end of the parent. It doesn't seem to be accomplishing what I want.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I feel like my `for(i=0; i<numchild; i++)` might be causing a parent and child to run in order with each iteration.  Does that appear to be correct?

Comment: I think you need to spend a bit more time learning about UNIX systems programming. `wait()` is for waiting for a child process to finish - there's no point putting it inside the branch for the child process, since the child doesn't have any children, and no processes to wait for. You still have the second `wait()` inside the loop that forks, so you're still forcing them to fork and then execute in order. Like I said, you need to wait for your children outside of that loop.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths the poster is reading/writing from the pipe where the parent can consume before the child get to it depending on the order.  At least in the example code thats put up.

Comment: @tijko: Yes, I know, the example code obviously doesn't work in the way he wants. He'll have to fix that behavior with `select()`, for instance.

Comment: @Tawm do you really need the overhead of `fork`ing?  Why not threads?

Comment: @tijko `fork()` and `pipe()` are required. So I feel like including threads might be redundant if `fork()` must already be used.

Comment: Besides the programming errors pointed out in the comments, you need to confirm the following before you can expect quicker results: 1) do you have a multi CPU system (either multiple cores or populated sockets)? 2) Is the running time to sum the numbers greater than the time to spawn a process and pipe data back and forth? (probably not) 3) Is there enough I/O bandwidth to sustain `numChild` simultaneous readers or will there be an I/O bottleneck? 4) With a single threaded solution what is the bottleneck you're seeing? Is a multi-process solution likely to alleviate that?

Comment: to make use of multiple CPUs, the code will need to use the `MPI` functionality.  Otherwise, irregardless of the number of CPUs, all the code will run on a single CPU.  With context switching, I/O delays, the multi process (using fork()) will take much longer that running the code straight line

Comment: @user3629249 I'm not using multiple CPUs, this is simply breaking up a file of numbers for multiple processes to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above, I conclude that:
 1. this is an assignment of some type
 2. it requires using [fork](/questions/tagged/fork) and [pipe](/questions/tagged/pipe)
If I were doing something like this for real (and it's not clear that it would be worth doing), I would probably be using threads queues and semaphores.

Given the constraints, I'll try to answer your question.

The problem is that you are have the parent code inside the for loop. So what is happening is that each time through the loop, the parent is spawning a child, then sending the offset information, then waiting for the result. So that forces the child to complete before the parent goes through the next iteration of the loop.

The answer is to have more than one loop. In the first loop, spawn all of the children. In the second loop, send the children their offsets. In the third loop, collect the results. In the fourth loop wait for the children to terminate. It would probably be faster if you sent the children their offsets in the first loop.

Another way to do this is to set the offset in a variable prior to doing each [fork](/questions/tagged/fork). That would obviate the need to use pipes for the input. I believe that you could also have each child just exit with the sum. Then the return exit status of the child could be the sum. The parent could just total the sums and you avoid using a return pipe. That would be a *better* way to do this -- though it wouldn't follow your apparent rules.

Comment: Hello lerman, I had worked on this program a bit last night, but forgotten to updated my question.  I have updated the code.  I feel like you're still correct about my `for()` loop causing issues, but it might be a different kind of problem now that I've implemented `select()`.